# Wondering about Encoding algorithm in Scikit-Learn

Tags: python, encoding, scikit-learn

I want to encode an ordinal variable. For example, the satisfaction from customers with 4 levels, Very Good, Good, Moderate, and Poor. I've tried using the `LabelEncoder` in `scikit-learn` library, but the encoding returns value of Very Good, which should be the best of all, of 2 instead of 3.

I'm wondering whether I can set the specific value for each level in the `LabelEncoder` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`OrdinalEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder) and provide your own mapping table. The format of the mapping table is a list of lists where the n-th lists holds the values in the n-th column of your input data.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
import random
import pandas as pd

# the categorical values in the right order
satisfaction = ['Poor', 'Moderate', 'Good', 'Very Good']

# create the mapping list
mapping = [satisfaction]

# create some random data but reproducible data
random.seed(42)
X = pd.DataFrame({'satisfaction': [random.choice(satisfaction) for _ in range(25)]})
print(X)
```

> ```
> 0          Poor 
> 1          Poor 
> 2          Good 
> 3          Moderate 
> 4          Moderate 
> 5          Moderate
> ```
>
> [...]

```
# create the encoder
enc = OrdinalEncoder(categories=mapping)

# transform your data
print(enc.fit_transform(X))
```

> ```
> [[0.]
>  [0.]
>  [2.]
>  [1.]
>  [1.]
>  [1.]
>  ...
> ]
> ```

Comment: I will try it. Thanks a lot.